# Can't do an in-place Update of an Azure cloud service (extended support) after a VIP swap - Public IP is in use (error)

Tags: services, azure, swap, cloud, software-update

I have successfully performed a VIP swap on a pair of Azure cloud services (extended support) that had Reserved IP addresses (static, although I don't think it matters).

Now I can Update (by uploading a new package) neither of them, although it had worked like a charm before the swap. In fact, I can't even complete the deployment (update) configuration form because of an error displayed for the Public IP address field.

It says: "The public IP address is currently in use by another resource. Choose a different resource group or create a new resource group". (The message part about the "group" feels hardly related.)

Note that I have corrected the cloud service configuration file so it referenced the IP Address that was assigned to the cloud service as a result of the swap.

E.g., the services are called cs1 and cs2, while the public addresses they used to use before the swap are ip1 and ip2. After the swap, cs1 is using the address ip2, which is clearly indicated by the cloud service current properties and configuration that can be seen via the portal.

So, I am updating cs1 having specified ip2 as its Reserved address:

```
      <ReservedIPs>
        <ReservedIP name="ip2"/>
      </ReservedIPs>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

Still, I am getting the error.

(I've tried to specify the "old" address, ip1, but it has correctly failed with "address cannot be changed". I've also tried to delete the second service, cs2, but it has not fixed the problem with the first one, cs1.)

(Another thing worth mentioning is that the config XML that can be exported from the cloud service page on the portal specifies the ReservedIP name attribute value as "Group MyServiceResourceGroupName ip2" - the classic way. I tried specifying it this way in my config, but the update failed saying config XML was malformed or something like that. Indeed, it has been working with just the resource name specified, no group spec, for all of the preceding deployments.)

Frankly, the problem looks like a bug, but how can I be sure?

Dear experts, would you please help?

Perhaps a workaround, if no solution. Otherwise, the VIP swap feature is hardly usable for the cloud services (extended support). It makes us choose: whether to update our services only by VIP swap, or only by Update with the service occasional complete recreation. Not quite convenient. We've been using a mix with the cloud services (classic).
I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thank you!

Vasily

Comment: In case anyone is wondering: VIP is Virtual IP Address. // I believe this is off-topic on Super User. We do not deal in cloud computing intricacies but only in what might happen inside a VM (within limits) and the like.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Daniel B! I admit I had not realized the SuperUser purpose and scope when I was posting my issue. I've already re-posted it on ServerFault as a more suitable forum. Would you recommend me to remove or close my issue on SuperUser?

Comment: Sure, as cross-posting is frowned upon. You should be able to delete it yourself or request deletion from a mod.